# Is it more efficient to use function args after branching (Python)?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that takes several arguments, one of which is a contact number. The data provided to the function is used to generate documents, and if one option is selected, that document is immediately returned inline, where the other option takes the contact number and generates an email. In the original version of this function, the contact number was immediately parsed at the start of the function, but I moved it into the else block as that is where the email is actually generated that uses that contact number and I saw no reason to create a new variable if it was not used half of the time. An example of this is below, and is built in Python using the Django framework:

```
def function(request, object, number=None):
    obj = ObjectItem.objects.get(id=object)
    # Originally number processed here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'inline' in request.POST:
            data = {
                'object': obj,
            }
            return generate_document(data, inline=True)
        else:
            if number:
                contact = '{}'.format(number)
            else:
                contact = obj.contact
            data = {
                'object': obj,
            }
            document = generate_document(data, inline=False)
            return message(document, contact)
    else:
        return redirect()
```

While looking at my code, I realize that I could move the data dict creation outside of the processing for the inline vs no inline in the POST, but I do not know if moving the processing of the number argument into the else block in that processing actually saves any time or is the more standard way of doing things. I know that as Python is a scripting language, there is not any kind of optimizations that would be performed automatically like they would rearranging that kind of declaration in a compiled language, so I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Measure it! The `timeit` module might be helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: In the "inline" case you don't even use `data` but do use something called `context`. In the `else` you create a variable called `contact` that you don't use. It seems this object is pretty small so its cost is not an issue. Trying to get rid of duplicate code is an issue but from the code you've shown us, I don't think those two docs are the same so you shouldn't build it in only one place.

Comment: @tdelaney I apparently missed some bits while anonymizing the code. Both functions generate the same document, but the method that does so accepts an argument on whether the document is to be displayed inline or not, which I have indicated in the updated code. Thanks for pointing out the errors in my example though, hopefully the updated code makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance perspective, it makes no difference whether you create `data` above the `if` or in the `if`. Python will only hit the line once and the dict will only be created once. But you should move it above the `if` for design reasons.

First, *don't repeat yourself*  - if you can reasonably implement a bit of code in one place, don't sprinkle it around your code. Suppose you decide a `defaultdict` is better later, you only have to change it in one place.

Second, placement implies intent. If you put it above your `if` you've made a statement that you plan to use that data structure everywhere. In your current code, readers will ask the same question you do... why wasn't that above the `if`? Its kinda trivial but the reading of the code shouldn't raise more questions.

Comment: Reading this, I believe that the best course of action (and what I am pretty sure I did) is to move the data declaration before the if since both the inline and message output generate documents with the same data, and placing the message number parsing into the else is good because that is the only place it will ever be used.